# how to change a drawableL icon size on a TextView?

Tags: android, xml, textview

hello everybady I want to use image in TextView but I can not change the size of image

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="person"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/person"
    ></TextView>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwLSC.png)

Comment: use imagebutton instead

Comment: I need TextView

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead use  android:layout_height="100dp" or anyother numberic value depending on the requiremnt

Comment: did it helped out the problem?

Comment: sorry no, I need change size image not the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Make use of Vector image. Seems from your question that you want to show an icon to your textview.

*In that case:*

**right-click on drawable folder -> new -> vector image -> click on the input space -> select the person image that you want (person) -> OK.**

now, once that vector is created, use it in your textview like:

```
android:drawableStart="@android/person_black"
```

**Solution 2:**

**right-click on res -> drawable -> size.xml**

**size.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/person"
      android:width="your_desired_size_value in dp"
      android:height="your_desired_size_value in dp"
      />

</layer-list >
```

Then, in your layout add:

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/size"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Wrap your resource in a drawable as follows and use its text view.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
      android:width="icon_width"
      android:height="icon_height"
      />

</layer-list >
```

Comment: but i dont know where I write it ??

Comment: Create as XML and put it drawable and use it from text view as you mention like     android:drawableStart="@drawable/person"

Comment: I created xml file "res>drawable>size.xml" : and I add in it your code 
there are problem in "icon_width" and "icon_height" value is Unknown

Comment: Yeah based on your needs create variable under dimens XML.